# How to read data passed in routed url in component angular

Tags: angular, router

I am new to angular 2+, and trying to learn.

I have a routes in angular like

```
const routes: Routes = [{path:"home",component:HomeComponent},                       
                        {path:"designer",component:DesignerComponent},
                        {path:"designer/:id",component:DesignerComponent}];
```

Once I reach on the `DesignerComponent` using the path `designer/:id`, I want to fetch the value "id". How can I do that? I am using latest version of angular.

Comment: Try with this 
`const = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **ActivatedRoute** and inside will have **snapshot.paramMap** you will get the parameter which you have passed.

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';

private userId = '';
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){

}

ngOnInit() {
   this.userId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
}
```

**OR**

ActivatedRoute.paramMap property is an Observable map of route parameters. The paramMap emits a new map of values that includes id when the user navigates to the component. In ngOnInit you subscribe to those values and set the ID.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
   switchMap(params => {
     // (+) before `params.get()` turns the string into a number
     this.userId = +params.get('id');
   })
 );
}
```

Comment: it will not work if user is on same root eg user is on  `designer/1` and navigate to `designer/2`

Comment: you can subscribe to `route.params` that will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two way first is

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
  this.userId=this.route.params.snapshot['id']
}
```

Other way you can subscribe to params like

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
      this.route.params.subscribe(data=>this.userId=data['id']
 })
    }
```

Go with second approach if your param can change while you are on the same root

Answer (score 0):

It is better to subscribe to the route, so you get the values everytime the `/:id` changes.

Add this code in the constructor of `DesignerComponent`class:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
    this.route.params.subscribe(data => this.userId = data['id'])
});
```

Comment: why you are posting duplicate answers here same way already specified below